# What is the address returned by the function from the stack?

Tags: c++, gdb, registry, stack, stack-frame

I have the following code

```
int isBST(struct node* node) 
{ 
  return(isBSTUtil(node, INT_MIN, INT_MAX)); 
} 

int isBSTUtil(struct node* node, int min, int max) 
{
  if (node==NULL) 
     return 1;      

  if (node->data <= min || node->data > max) 
     return 0; 

  return
    isBSTUtil(node->left, min, node->data) &&  // Allow only distinct values
    isBSTUtil(node->right, node->data, max);  // Allow only distinct values
}
```

When I do debug the code in GDB, I see that the second parameter is set by address ebp + 0xc (0xbffff188+0xc), the third parameter is set to ebp + 0x10 and the first parameter is not clear where, in theory, we know that the return address of the function is located EBP + 4 , the first parameter is located EBP +8 and ....from what I have so ?

Comment: +1 good question, but **please plase don't post screenshots.**

Comment: ok, I deleted a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

In theory, we don't know anything about where the arguments or
the return address is located.  On a specific architecture, we
can (usually) figure out what a specific compiler does by
examining some of the generated assembler.  The *first* thing to
examine is the function preable.  On an Intel 32 bit processor,
the frame pointer will be in EBP, and it will be set up *after*
a certain number of push to save registers.  (In particular,
there must be a `push EBP` before EBP is set up for the local
frame.)  A typical preable for an Intel might be:

```
function:
        PUSH EBP
        MOV  EBP, ESP
        SUB  ESP, n         ;   allocate space for local variables
```

Beyond that: the Intel stack grows down, and compilers
for Intel almost universally push the arguments from right to
left, so in your case, `max` will have the highest address,
`min` will be right below it, and `node` below that.  So your
image of the frame will be:

```
[EBP - ...]     local variables
[EBP + 0]       the pushed old EBP
[EBP + 4]       the return address
[EBP + 8]       the first argument (node)
[EBP + 12]      the second argument (min)
[EBP + 16]      the third argument (max)
```

(This is supposing that the arguments are all 32 bit values.)
Of course, a compiler might push additional registers before
pushing EBP, causing the offsets to be correspondingly higher.
This is just one possible layout.